# Trying to access Text property from ASP:Textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a apsx with the following code:

```
<div class="form-group col-6 mx-auto">
    <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" name="username_box" ID="username_box"
         runat="server" placeholder="Username" TextMode="SingleLine"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
</div>

<div class="form-group col-6 mx-auto">
    <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" ID="password_box" runat="server"
         placeholder="Password" TextMode="Password"> </asp:TextBox>
    <br /> 
</div>

<div class="form-group d-grid gap-2 col-6 mx-auto">
    <asp:LinkButton class="btn btn-danger btn-block" ID="login_button" runat="server"
         text="Login" OnClick="Loginbutton_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
    <br />
</div>
```

When a user enters the username in the first `TextBox` (ID:`username_box`) and enters the password on button click the Code Behind should capture the `username_box.Text` value. However it always return `null`. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, please your assistance.

See code behind.

```
protected void Loginbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    username = username_box.Text;
    Response.Write(username);
}
```

I am expecting the entered value from the `username_box.Text` property however I receive nothing.
I looked as `IsPostBack` but I am not sure I am looking at it properly.

Comment: is `ViewState` enabled? have you checked using browser console that the values are actually sent?

Comment: oh right, also that HTML `name` property on the first `TextBox` is redundant, ASP.Net Webform has their own conventions, please tread carefully.

Comment: @Bagus Tesa after updating the ASP:Textbox declaration with EnableViewState="true", I receive the same result.

Answer (score 2):

I found the error that was made. There was another form within the main form on the Site1.Master page. Further reading indicated that is not allowed.

I removed the nested form and the values were retrieved. Thank you for your support.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).